# VS Code, Bracket Pair Colorizer does not work. Do I have to make a donation to make it work? I have turned on all setting with no luck

Tags: javascript, parsing, visual-studio-code, ide

Turn on all setting correctly. Not working. However, I few weeks ago is was working. I
get a message that they are asking for a donation. Is is legal? And will it work after
the donation? I would live without it, but is is a very nice and effective feature!

Comment: Yes, it's legal, but you also don't need it as a separate plugin as VSCode adopted it as part of their native code back in 2021. [Here's some information](https://www.stefanjudis.com/snippets/how-to-configure-vs-code-bracket-colors/).

Comment: you have to enable the native version with a setting, search for `bracket` in settings GUI

Answer (score 11):

I finally found the dang culprit! This line was basically overwriting all of my bracket-related settings:

```
// "editor.language.brackets": [],
```

Just commented it out and now these all work with my theme and no need for another extension!

```
"editor.bracketPairColorization.enabled": true,
"editor.bracketPairColorization.independentColorPoolPerBracketType": true,
"editor.guides.bracketPairs": true,
```

Comment: This is the right answer

Answer (score 7):

If you are facing trouble activating the default bracket pair colorizer then here are the steps to follow. In VS Code, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd> > type json in search box > click on Open User Settings(JSON). In settings.json file, search for 'bracket' > delete all bracket-related entries.

Now just write below 2 lines anywhere after putting a comma at the end of the line before them :

`"editor.bracketPairColorization.enabled": true,`

`"editor.guides.bracketPairs": true,`

Comment: vscode has bracket colorizer by default. You don't need the plugin. [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/blogs/2021/09/29/bracket-pair-colorization#_what-we-did)

Comment: Yeah that's what I said, how to activate the default bracket pair colorizer, if anyone having problem to activate the default one

Comment: ok.. I figured you were refering to the plugin since you are having `"bracket-pair-colorizer-2.depreciation-notice"` If you do have the plugin around, you an uninstall it

Answer (score 4):

Bracket Pair Colorizer is no longer maintained. It's outdated.

Instead, you can colorize your brackets by adding this single line to your **settings.json**:

```
"editor.bracketPairColorization.enabled": true
```

Comment: Still, It is not working for me.

Answer (score 1):

**Bracket pair colorizer functionality is now built into VS Code. So don't even install that extension.**

even if you keep the below line in settings.json, there is no difference

```
{ 
"editor.bracketPairColorization.enabled": true,
"editor.guides.bracketPairs": "active"
}
```

Comment: No need of doing this anymore, because bracket pair colorizer functionality is now built into VS Code. Even if you add these lines of code. Doesn't make any difference.

Answer (score 0):

> 1. Bracket pair colorizer functionality is now built into VS Code. So don't even install that extension.

[image]

> 2.Even if you add the below line in settings.json file
>
> ```
>   { 
>     "editor.bracketPairColorization.enabled": true,                                       
>     "editor.guides.bracketPairs": "active"
>   }
> ```

- Doesn't make any difference.
- No need of donation, and even turning on any setting.